# DirectX 10.1 / C++: How to render text on sprite over ID3D10Resource* textures?

Tags: c++, text, textures, sprite, directx-10

In DirectX 10/10.1, I want to render text on all four corners of the multiple displays that display a texture each made up of `ID3D10Resource* prcST` using `D3DX10CreateTextureFromFile()` in my function `HRESULT OnD3D10CreateDevice( DEVICE_OBJECT* pDeviceObj, WINDOW_OBJECT* pWindowObj )`

```
D3DX10CreateTextureFromFile ( pDeviceObj->pDevice, L"tile1.jpg", NULL, NULL, &prcST, &hr );
```

When I use something like below in my `OnD3D10rameRender()` function, that uses sprite to render text, my textures are not rendered, but only text is rendered with black backgound.( Text on black background.

Text rendered at each top-left of the 3 displays is "Some text to render"
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AnandMuglikar/posts/XLNnBRCtTfa

```
hr = pDeviceObj->pSprite->Begin(0);
std::wstring left = L"Some text to render";
RECT r;
r.top = 0;
r.bottom = pWindowObj->Height;
r.left = 0;
r.right = pWindowObj->Width;
hr = pDeviceObj->pFont->DrawTextW(pDeviceObj->pSprite, left.c_str(), -1, &r, DT_LEFT | DT_TOP | DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOCLIP, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, .5f));
hr = pDeviceObj->pSprite->Flush();
hr = pDeviceObj->pSprite->End();
pDeviceObj->pDevice->OMSetBlendState(NULL, 0, 0x0000ffff);
```

How to render text on sprite over alpha-blended `ID3D10Resource*` textures?

The 3 Edge-blending textures on 3 displays are as seen here:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AnandMuglikar/posts/MSVdrfFpAuW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great job getting the text rendered on screen.  Are you using a quad for the texture?  Textures need an array of vertices in order to be displayed.  The createtexture function only loads the image data into a texture object.  You then have to pass the texture object, along with an ordered set of vertices to form a mesh that will be used to display the texture.

Comment: I'm creating a 101*101 mesh to display the texture and its being rendered correctly. No problems with that. However, it is a new requirement to display some numbers (text) over this texture. (Please see the images in the 2 links I have shared).

Now the problem is when I use the code for rendering text, it is being rendered on a blank (black) screen, but the texture isn't rendered.

For now, I've used OpenCV to render text on the image itself by using imwrite().

Comment: so before you were using text, you were able to see the image a texture on screen, though when you add the text, you get a blackscreen, but the text is being rendered?  blackscreen usually means the texture isn't being read correctly.  it might be you that the sprite renderer is clearing the device context, so you might have to pass in the texture after you write your text.  trying sending the texture after you write the text... you are writing your text after setting the texture currently?